# React hooks set parent data from child component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to React.

I am getting array of record from parent data and trying to update record data using setRecords. Is there a way to update parent state from child state?

```
{
    homeTeamName: "Blue"
    homeTeamId: 1
    homeScore: 1
    awayTeamName: "Red"
    awayTeamId: 2
    awayScore: 1
    scheduledAt: "2020-01-01T00:00:00"
    location: "Fort Lee, NJ"
    league: null
    leagueId: 1
    club: null
    clubId: 1
    matchRecords: Array(4)
    0: {scoreMemberId: 2, scoreMemberName: "Jake Kwon2", scoreTeamId: 1, assistMemberId: 1, assistMemberName: "Jake Kwon1", …}
    1: {scoreMemberId: 1, scoreMemberName: "Jake Kwon1", scoreTeamId: 1, assistMemberId: 2, assistMemberName: "Jake Kwon2", …}
    2: {scoreMemberId: 3, scoreMemberName: "Jake Kwon3", scoreTeamId: 2, assistMemberId: 4, assistMemberName: "Jake Kwon4", …}
    3: {scoreMemberId: 4, scoreMemberName: "Jake Kwon4", scoreTeamId: 2, assistMemberId: 3, assistMemberName: "Jake Kwon3", …}
}

const RecordItem = ({ record, teamId, memberOptions, isAdmin }) => {
 const [records, setRecords] = useState(record);
  const { scoreMemberId, scoreMemberName, assistMemberId, assistMemberName } = records;

  useEffect(() => {
    setRecords(record)
  }, [record]);


      <CustomDropdown
            name='member'
            value={scoreMemberId}
            handleChange={member => setRecords({ ...records, scoreMemberId: member.value })}
            options={memberOptions.filter(member => member.teamId === teamId)}
            required
        />
```

Comment: React has the unidirectional data flow. The state is stored in a parent and passed down to a child. The parent can pass the child a callback function prop to update state. The child can call the callback function prop, which will update the state in the parent, and then the child will be re-rendered with updated props from the parent. Are you hoping to track the item selected in `<CustomDropdown />` and store it in state of the `<RecordItem />` component?

Comment: Calling `handleChange` from the `CustomDropdown` should update the parent's state.

Comment: You mentioned Redux in the previous question - does this mean you have a full Redux store in the app? If so, you want to bring in the `useDispatch()` hook (Ref: [Redux Hooks](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks)) and dispatch an action to update the store, which will then (presumably) update the parent.

Comment: If no Redux, or you only want the parent to update and not the store, then @thor83 has a simple solution with the callback prop. You should probably show the parent component to get an answer.